# Which collection class in java breaks the S.O.L.I.D Principle?

Tags: java, ooad

I was asked in an interview about which collection breaks the S.O.L.I.D principle??

Can anyone explain which one is it and how?

Comment: I agree, seems to be genuine question.

Comment: I was asked about this which i did not had a answer to,how do you suggest i should format it?? any suggestion would be welcome

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Java provides a generic collection called [`IdentityHashMap<K,V>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/IdentityHashMap.html), which breaks Liskov substitution principle - the "L" in SOLID by intentionally violating `Map<K,V>`'s contract.

Here is a note from the documentation of the `IdentityHashMap<K,V>` class:

> This class is not a general-purpose Map implementation! While this class implements the Map interface, it intentionally violates Map's general contract, which mandates the use of the equals method when comparing objects. This class is designed for use only in the rare cases wherein reference-equality semantics are required.

Comment: Does java.lang.string break open-closed since it is final?

Comment: @Khanna111GauravKhanna Technically - yes, it breaks the "O" part. However, `String` is not a Java collection, and making it `final` was definitely the right thing to do from the security standpoint.

Comment: Yes, I missed out on the collection part.

Comment: What about HashMap.put()? It allows null key and values. But general Map interface says to throw NullPointerException when a key or value is null